# Visual Studio Code cl.exe compile C2059 , C3536 errors

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  auto result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

I run this code for testing compilers and clang++ and g++ compiler worked but i did not able to run it on cl++ compiler what should i do? (I am trying to learn c++ from freecodecamp.org)

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "Build with GCC 12.0.1",
        "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++20",
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "Build with Clang 14.0.4",
        "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++20",
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "Build With Cl 19.31.31107",
        "command": "cl.exe",
        "args": [
            "/Zi",
            "/EHsc",
            "/Fe",
            "${fileDirname}\\mehmet.exe",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$msCompile"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
    }
]
```

}

This big mess is my task.json. I configured g++, cl++, clang++ compilers.
Cl and clang added from visual studio codes terminal tab, cl++ added from dev powershell prompt.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `/std:c++20` in your CL configuration. Without that, there ain't no `<=>` operator.

Comment: What does cl say? The precise error message would contain the answer to your question, most likely. Also, check that the compiler you use actually supports the version of the language you have, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp20

Comment: "but i did not able to run it on cl++ compiler" - what does that mean? does it mean that CL.exe is not even started?